# how can i pass this info?

Tags: android

In the following list.java i am making a URL near the bottom that grabs the current location and adds it to the URL. I have a PHP script taking the location from the URL and then doing its thing and returning a Array based off JSON. I need to get the URL string to be accessed in the HttpPost located in the oncreate area of my Code.

```
public class List extends ListActivity {

    int ct_id;
    String[] ct_number = null;
    String[] ct_address = null;
    String[] ct_phone = null;
    String[] ct_fax = null;
    String[] ct_email = null;
    String[] ct_city = null;
    String[] ct_province = null;
    String[] ct_country = null;
    String[] ct_pcode = null;
    String[] ct_lat = null;
    String[] ct_long = null;
    String[] ct_distance = null;
    String[] ct_show = null;
    String[] ct_listinfo = null;

    MyLocation myLocation = new MyLocation();

    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.timslist);
        findCurrentLocation();

        String result = null;
        InputStream is = null;
        StringBuilder sb = null;
        //http post
        try{

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                    //This is where i need the myurl string to be accessed
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Need_the_myurl_String_here);

            //httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
        }
        //convert response to string
        try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");
            String line="0";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result=sb.toString();
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result"+e.toString());
        }
        //paring data
        JSONArray jArray;
        try{
            jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            JSONObject json_data=null;
            ct_number=new String[jArray.length()];
            ct_address=new String[jArray.length()];
            ct_phone=new String[jArray.length()];
            ct_fax=new String[jArray.length()];
            ct_email=new String[jArray.length()];
            ct_city=new String[jArray.length()];
            ct_province=new String[jArray.length()];
            ct_country=new String[jArray.length()];
            ct_pcode=new String[jArray.length()];
            ct_lat=new String[jArray.length()];
            ct_long=new String[jArray.length()];
            ct_distance=new String[jArray.length()];
            ct_listinfo=new String[jArray.length()];
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                ct_id=json_data.getInt("location_id");
                ct_number[i]=json_data.getString("store_number");
                ct_address[i]=json_data.getString("store_address");
                ct_phone[i]=json_data.getString("store_phone");
                ct_fax[i]=json_data.getString("store_fax");
                ct_email[i]=json_data.getString("store_email");
                ct_city[i]=json_data.getString("store_city");
                ct_province[i]=json_data.getString("store_province");
                ct_country[i]=json_data.getString("store_country");
                ct_pcode[i]=json_data.getString("store_pcode");
                ct_lat[i]=json_data.getString("store_lat");
                ct_long[i]=json_data.getString("store_long");
                ct_distance[i]=json_data.getString("store_distance");
                ct_listinfo[i] = new String (ct_address[i] + "\n" + ct_city[i] + ", " + ct_province[i] + " - " + ct_distance[i] + " Km Away");
            }
        }
        catch(JSONException e1){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Locations Found" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (ParseException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.listview,ct_listinfo));
        ListView lv;
        lv = getListView();
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        lv.setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        lv.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> timslist, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ListMore.class);

                i.putExtra("ct_number_pass", ct_number[position]);
                i.putExtra("ct_address_pass", ct_address[position]);
                i.putExtra("ct_phone_pass", ct_phone[position]);
                i.putExtra("ct_city_pass", ct_city[position]);
                i.putExtra("ct_province_pass", ct_province[position]);
                i.putExtra("ct_country_pass", ct_country[position]);
                i.putExtra("ct_pcode_pass", ct_pcode[position]);
                i.putExtra("ct_distance_pass", ct_distance[position]);

                startActivity(i);

            }
        });
    }

    private void findCurrentLocation() {
        myLocation.getLocation(this, locationResult);
    }

    public LocationResult locationResult = new LocationResult() {

        @Override
        public void gotLocation(Location location) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (location != null) {

                    //Here is the String i am trying to access
                String myurl  = "http://www.doamin.com/list.php?lat=" + location.getLatitude() + "&long=" + location.getLongitude();

            }
        }
    };
}
```

I have tried with the help of others but cant seem to get this working right so i am trying to see if there is a easy and workable solution out there.

Comment: Not sure if I understand but you want to execute the POST request after you have the GPS location (when gotLocation() was called)?

Comment: Yes the URL from `gotLocation()` needs to be able to work with `HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Need_the_myurl_String_here);`

Comment: Why you don't put your code what you need to be called on a separate method and call that method after String myurl  = "http://www.doamin.com/list.php?lat=" + location.getLatitude() + "&long=" + location.getLongitude(); ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this: you are trying to access the location value BEFORE it is returned to you. You should:

1. Add a Handler instance to your class.
2. Move the HttpClient/HttpPost calls into a separate method.
3. Send a Message to the Handler from the `gotLocation` method with the location data.
4. Call that method from the Handler with the location data from step 3 above.

EDIT: try creating a method like this:

```
void updateData(String url)
{
        String result = null;
        InputStream is = null;
        StringBuilder sb = null;
        //http post
        try{

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                    //This is where i need the myurl string to be accessed
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

            //httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
        }
        //convert response to string
        try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");
            String line="0";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result=sb.toString();
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result"+e.toString());
        }
        //paring data
        JSONArray jArray;
        try{
            jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            JSONObject json_data=null;
            ct_number=new String[jArray.length()];
            ct_address=new String[jArray.length()];
            ct_phone=new String[jArray.length()];
            ct_fax=new String[jArray.length()];
            ct_email=new String[jArray.length()];
            ct_city=new String[jArray.length()];
            ct_province=new String[jArray.length()];
            ct_country=new String[jArray.length()];
            ct_pcode=new String[jArray.length()];
            ct_lat=new String[jArray.length()];
            ct_long=new String[jArray.length()];
            ct_distance=new String[jArray.length()];
            ct_listinfo=new String[jArray.length()];
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                ct_id=json_data.getInt("location_id");
                ct_number[i]=json_data.getString("store_number");
                ct_address[i]=json_data.getString("store_address");
                ct_phone[i]=json_data.getString("store_phone");
                ct_fax[i]=json_data.getString("store_fax");
                ct_email[i]=json_data.getString("store_email");
                ct_city[i]=json_data.getString("store_city");
                ct_province[i]=json_data.getString("store_province");
                ct_country[i]=json_data.getString("store_country");
                ct_pcode[i]=json_data.getString("store_pcode");
                ct_lat[i]=json_data.getString("store_lat");
                ct_long[i]=json_data.getString("store_long");
                ct_distance[i]=json_data.getString("store_distance");
                ct_listinfo[i] = new String (ct_address[i] + "\n" + ct_city[i] + ", " + ct_province[i] + " - " + ct_distance[i] + " Km Away");
            }
        }
        catch(JSONException e1){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Locations Found" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (ParseException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.listview,ct_listinfo));
        ListView lv;
        lv = getListView();
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        lv.setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        lv.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> timslist, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ListMore.class);

                i.putExtra("ct_number_pass", ct_number[position]);
                i.putExtra("ct_address_pass", ct_address[position]);
                i.putExtra("ct_phone_pass", ct_phone[position]);
                i.putExtra("ct_city_pass", ct_city[position]);
                i.putExtra("ct_province_pass", ct_province[position]);
                i.putExtra("ct_country_pass", ct_country[position]);
                i.putExtra("ct_pcode_pass", ct_pcode[position]);
                i.putExtra("ct_distance_pass", ct_distance[position]);

                startActivity(i);

            }
        });

}

void updateList(final String url)
{
   getListView().post(new Runnable(){ public void run(){ updateData(url); }});
}
```

and then do this in `gotLocation`:

```
@Override
        public void gotLocation(Location location) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (location != null) {

                    //Here is the String i am trying to access
                    updateList("http://www.doamin.com/list.php?lat=" + location.getLatitude() + "&long=" + location.getLongitude());
            }
        }
```

You'll need to fix up any compile errors, but something like this should work for you.

Comment: Every time i move the HTTPPost this breaks my code and the list dose not work. I don't understand how i would go about this.

Comment: `Return type for the method is missing

Syntax error on token "url", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token

The type new Runnable(){} must implement the inherited abstract method Runnable.run()

url cannot be resolved to a type`

Any Ideas?

Comment: I have been playing with your example but cant seem to get it to work i have gone back to my posted code in hope of finding a way to make this work. What i cant understand is why i am getting the above errors or how to fix them. I would thing what i am trying to is a simple thing. maybe i should re-look at the option of making my script just get current location and continue on with the HttpPost?

Comment: Meh. No writing code when I'm hungry. I left the `public void run(){}` out of the `updateData` method.

Comment: The expectation wasn't that this would work perfectly, but it would show one method by which you could pass your URL to your HttpPost. Fundamentally you CAN'T use in `onCreate` something that is generated by a callback that is initiated in `onCreate`: you HAVE to run your request after the fact, and this tries to wrap up the logic for the HttpPost so once the location information is available you can invoke it with the GPS data. I edited my answer: should fix the error above.

Comment: Yes that did fix the errors but i think again i'm in over my head. I am currently doing some reading on android. I am not 100% sure how to call my list now using the code. I thank you for your help.